# Excel Interop Reference

Tags: .net, excel-interop

First question on Stack Overflow here.

So I'm using Visual Studio 2012, and I'm trying to test out a few functions I wrote in C++ in a separate file. The project I'm working on uses an MVVM model, so the main control loop is in a C# file that backs the User Interface, which is where I'm trying to get it to automatically write some values to an excel file. To get started, I'm just trying to get it to write a value (any value) to a new excel file, but I've been stuck on this:

```
    private void resultsToExcel()
    {

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook oWB;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet oSheet;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range oRng;

        object misvalue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

       oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
       oXL.Visible = true;
       oXL.UserControl = true;

       oWB = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add(""));
       oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)oXL.Sheets["Sheet1"];
```

Everything seems to work fine at the Application Object level and at the Workbook level, but when I get down to trying to create an object that directs down to the Excel Sheet, I keep getting this error on the last line (the one that refers to the new sheet object):

> (local variable) Excel.Application oXL
>
> Error:    One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression
>   cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?

Kind of driving me crazy because no matter how I rework this sheet object, I keep getting the same error. Also checked in the project's Reference Manager (many... many times) to make sure that I've included all the right Assembly extension references, and I've included Microsoft.Office.Tools, Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel, Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.v4.0.Utilities, and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.

So I have no idea what reference could be missing. I thought maybe it's a syntax issue, but the syntax I'm using matches what I've found on other Stack Overflow questions in my extensive research on this problem.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You must add a reference to Microsoft.CSharp.  it is normally there when you create a new project, maybe this project got started on an old version of VS.

Comment: Looks like it worked - thanks, Hans!